# AngularJS : wait for function to respond in factory. For asynchronous communication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a button that passes search word to the factory :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="searchFactory(search_name)">Search</button>
```

and the factory calls the websocket which returns JSON.

```
var angularjsapp = angular.module('graphApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angularjsapp.factory('searchFactory', function() {
      //return $resource('friends.json');
      return {
            myfunc:function(search_name){
                console.log('ok')
                keyword_type = 1
                WebSocketTest(search_name,keyword_type)

                }
            }   
    });

angularjsapp.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function($scope,searchFactory) {
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.namesPerPage = 10
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.searchFactory = searchFactory.myfunc;
 });
```

and then I want to display that JSON back to the html. For that I need 2 things . 1st wait for the websocket function so that it returns the JSON and then get that value in the cotroller to display back. Any ideas how that can be done?

Answer (score 1):

ok u need to use a promise to wait until the websocket  return the data.
try something like this

```
angularjsapp.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function($scope,searchFactory) {
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.namesPerPage = 10
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.searchFactory = function(search_name){
      searchFactory.myfunc(search_name).then(function(response){
         //success `enter code here`
       },function(){
         //error`enter code here`
       })
   }
 });
```

// factory

```
angularjsapp.factory('searchFactory', function($q) { 
      return {
            myfunc:function(search_name){
                console.log('ok')
                keyword_type = 1;  
                  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                       if (WebSocketTest(search_name,keyword_type)) {
                         resolve('sucess result');
                       } else {
                        reject('error result');
                       }
                     }, 1000);
                   });            
                }
            }   
    });
```

Comment: I think it will not work.  callback(data) will not wait for the response of WebSocketTest(search_name,keyword_type).

Comment: @IT13122256 Ranawaka R.A.S.M The syntax of the controller is wrong : SyntaxError: Unexpected token )  at  `searchFactory.myfunc(search_name,function**)**`

Comment: @Bilas Sarke your input would be much appreciated

Comment: The olace where you have written : `enter code here` doesn't wait for websocket function

Comment: replace this resolve('sucess result'); from resolve(WebSocketTest(search_name,keyword_type));  this and try again

Comment: @IT13122256RanawakaR.A.S.M still the function websocket is called after   `enter code  here`  part